# Scanner crashes catch statement

Tags: java

I'm having issues with catch statements crashing when I try to use a scanner within them. I'm making a simple rock paper scissors program for my comp sci class and my goal is to make it virtually impossible to crash. Here is my code:

```
public class RPS {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random gen = new Random();
    int rounds = 0, choice, playerchoice = 0, complete, playerwins, compwins;
    String cont = "y";

    System.out.println("Rock, Paper, Scissors!");

    while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(cont)) {
        complete = 0;
        playerwins = 0;
        compwins = 0;
        System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?"
                + " (1, best of 3, or best of 5)");

        while (true) {

            try {
                rounds = scan.nextInt();
                while (rounds != 1 && rounds != 3 && rounds != 5) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number of rounds.");
                    System.out.println("One game, best of 3, or best of 5?");
                    rounds = scan.nextInt();
                }
                break;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                while (rounds != 1 && rounds != 3 && rounds != 5) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number of rounds.");
                    System.out.println("One game, best of 3, or best of 5?");
                    rounds = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
```

My code advances perfectly fine unless netbeans throws an InputMismatchException in the try block. While the catch statement is supposed to stop this kind of thing, it still crashes and I have no idea why.

As I am a measly high school student, I apologize for any terrible coding practices I may be using. My only goal it to get this to work.

Comment: You should add the stacktrace to your question. It will tell us what exactly fails in your catch block.
You can print the stacktrace by adding: `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch-block before your while.

Answer (score 1):

Try{this} / Catch{that} is like saying "Try this, and if that doesn't work, do that". The issue here is that you put the same code in the catch block as in the try block. Imagine this:

1. We enter the Try block
2. User inputs something that isn't valid
3. Therefore, we go to the catch block
4. Now, the user is in the catch block and they input something invalid
5. Now we've failed, but we have nowhere left to go! We're already in the catch block.
6. We fail out

scan.nextInt(); will fail whenever it receives an invalid input, so any time you call that function it should be within a try block.

Thus, this can be solved simply by leaving the catch block blank (or just printing "Please input a valid number of rounds!" and doing nothing else). If we fail into the catch block, nothing will happen, we'll hit the while loop and come back around to the try block for another stab at it.

Comment: When I delete the code from the catch block (or just put a println command) it gets stuck in the catch block infinitely. Is there a way I can go back to the try block and run that code again so they can input a valid number? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make sure you don't include a while loop inside of the catch block, otherwise it could be getting stuck in that loop within the catch. If you've already removed the while loop and it's still failing, please show the updated code